# SQL server aggregate function query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table called MusicTrack with the columns MusicTrackID, TrackName and Duration.

I am using the query:

```
    Select Cast(DateAdd( ms,SUM(DateDiff( ms, '00:00:00', Duration)), '00:00:00' ) as time) 
as 'Total duration' from   
    MusicTrack  where MusicTrackID = '1' or MusicTrackID = '3'
```

This query adds the durations of the 2 selected music tracks together and displays it in a temporary column called total duration. The 'Duration' is of datatype Time, so I am converting it to integer and back again.

My question: what way can I adapt the query to also include include the TrackName field and a running total duration? Or include the temporary column as well as the TrackName column.

So that the display will have TrackName and Total duration... along the lines of:

```
TrackName   Duration   Total duration

Name1       00:03:00     00:03:00
Name2       00:03:01     00:06:01
```

I tried to just include the TrackName column to the query like this, but it doesn't work:

```
Select TrackName, Cast(....) From MusicTrack  where MusicTrackID = '1' or MusicTrackID = '3'
```

Comment: Research "running total" in SQL

Answer (score 2):

try below

**i created one sample table**

```
SELECT * INTO TMPTIME 
 FROM (
SELECT 1 AS ID ,'Name1' AS NAME,'00:03:00' AS T    
UNION 
SELECT 2 AS ID,'Name2' AS NAME,'00:03:01' AS T    
UNION
SELECT  3 AS ID,'Name3' AS NAME,'00:03:02' AS T   
UNION
SELECT 4 AS ID,'Name4' AS NAME,'00:03:41' AS T    
)TMP
```

**output query**

```
SELECT ID,NAME, T AS TIME,
(SELECT 
cast(DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', cast (t as time) )), '00:00:00.000') as time)
FROM TMPTIME T1 WHERE T1.ID<=TMPTIME.ID
) AS TOTAL

 FROM TMPTIME
```

result

```
ID  NAME    TIME    TOTAL
1   Name1   00:03:00    00:03:00.0000000
2   Name2   00:03:01    00:06:01.0000000
3   Name3   00:03:02    00:09:03.0000000
4   Name4   00:03:41    00:12:44.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/60f41/1/0) for SQL Server (not mySQL)

```
SELECT TrackName, Duration, Cast(DateAdd(ms,RunningTotal,'00:00:00') as time) as 'Total Duration'
FROM
(SELECT TrackName, Duration,
  SUM(DateDiff(ms,'00:00:00',Duration)) OVER(ORDER BY MusicTrackId 
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
      AS RunningTotal
  FROM MusicTrack
  WHERE MusicTrackId IN (1,3)
)T
```

syntax found here [running total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver)

for mySql [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60f41/19/0), (NOT SQL Server)

```
SELECT TrackName,Date_Format(Duration,'%k:%i:%s') as Duration,
                 Date_Format(runningTotal,'%k:%i:%s') as 'Total Duration'
FROM
  (SELECT TrackName, Duration,
          Sec_To_Time(@total:=@total + Time_To_Sec(Duration)) as runningTotal
   FROM MusicTrack,(SELECT @total:='00:00:00')T
   WHERE MusicTrackId IN (1,3)
   ORDER BY MusicTrackId
  )Result
```